# How to findviewbyid 100 EditTex in a TableLayout

Tags: android, android-edittext, tablelayout

I have put 100 edittext objects in a tablelayout,how could I use findviewbyid to find those editext objects ? so I could get the text from those edittext whcih user have entered ?

Comment: 100 edittext seem a bit too much for a tablelayout, it might be better to use a ListView ore similar solution with an adapter.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep an ArrayList to hold the EditText like

```
ArrayList<EditText> editTextArray=new ArrayList<EditText>();
```

And add each EditText

```
editTextArray.add(editText1);
```

So , you can invoke  as follows

```
editTextArray.get(i).getText();
```